# Do I need to run git init everytime I change the path of my local files?

Tags: git

For instance, I ran git init, added its remote and pulled the files and pushed my local changes to the same remote, then I decided to change the local path of the files on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do `git init` again as long as you copy the hidden `.git/` directory in the root of your project.

See [how to show hidden files and folder on Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5), then copy `.git/` into your new local path.

- [Show hidden files on Mac](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/show-hidden-files-mac-3520878/)
- [Show hidden files on Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/hide-folders-and-show-hidden-files-in-ubuntu-beginner-trick/)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Now I understand.